# Can't cd to / in docker while creating new image

Tags: windows, docker

I have copied following code from some website to create docker image of my own. Have zero experience in docker. I am stuck at very basic command of cd'ing into the directory, which I feel is same from ages for linux based systems unless docker is expecting some special format. Please help me resolve it.

```
    Operating system: Windows 10 home
    Docker Desktop
   

     Problem: Step 5/12 : ADD opencv.sh /home/opencv.sh
         ---> Using cache
         ---> 17d5d7c7ae7c
        Step 6/12 : RUN /home/opencv.sh
         ---> Running in 27fd8c2d3dd3
        /home/opencv.sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /
        '...ing into '3.4.9
```

Below are docker file and opencv.sh file which is being run from inside docker file.

Contents of DockerFile

```
    FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.2-py3-jupyter
    RUN apt-get update
    RUN apt-get upgrade -y
    RUN apt-get install git cmake wget unzip -y
    ADD opencv.sh /home/opencv.sh
    RUN /home/opencv.sh
```

Contents of opencv.sh

```
    cd /
    git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git --single-branch 3.4.9
    mv 3.4.9 cv
    cd cv
    mkdir build
    cd build
    cmake ..
    make
    make install
```

Comment: I think you might have some CRLF (windows style) line breaks in your files, you can check with for example Notepad++. There should only be LF (Unix style line breaks) at the end of the lines.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you (he) want to use shell script file when it's possible just to use docker?
You can try this

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.2-py3-jupyter

RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install git cmake wget curl -y

WORKDIR /
RUN git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git --single-branch 3.4.9
RUN mv 3.4.9 cv
RUN mkdir cv/build
RUN cd cv/build && cmake .. && make && make install
```

Comment: True, with this aproach builds are much faster because of docker build cache.